# How to create Burst test in Jmeter without using parallel threads?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a requirement to create simple Burst test in Jmeter:

- 10 requests-> 20 requests -> 30 requests

On single worker mode.
Throughput 20ms
Anticipated response time : <=200ms

How can we achieve this with Jmeter without using parallel threads?
I am looking for a simple solution.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Add plugin 
[Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) to JMeter

Add Ultimate Thread Group component with settings of 3 rows

Set Start Threads Count 10,20 and 30

Use different start times so requests batch will be executed in different times

> "Ultimate" means there will be no need in further Thread Group plugins. The features that everyone needed in JMeter and they finally available:
>
> - infinite number of schedule record
> - separate ramp-up time, shutdown time, flight time for each schedule record
> - and, of course, trustworthy load preview graph

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Do you have sample example / instruction guide on how to use it? thanks

Comment: @user2451016 see link, it's pretty intuitive replacement for JMeter's thread group, each line represent *Burst*

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) and [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) combination which provides flexible way of defining load patterns:

[image]

They can be connected together using [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) so JMeter will be able to kick off more threads in order to reach the desired throughput (number of requests per second) if current amount is not enough.

Both can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Do you have sample example / instruction guide on how to use it? thanks